# TypeError: len is not well defined for symbolic Tensors. (activation_3/Identity:0) Please call `x.shape` rather than `len(x)` for shape information

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning, keras-rl

I am trying to implement a DQL model on one game of openAI gym. But it's giving me following error.

> TypeError: len is not well defined for symbolic Tensors.
>   (activation_3/Identity:0) Please call `x.shape` rather than `len(x)`
>   for shape information.

Creating a gym environment:

```
ENV_NAME = 'CartPole-v0'

env = gym.make(ENV_NAME)
np.random.seed(123)
env.seed(123)
nb_actions = env.action_space.n
```

My model looks like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(1,) + env.observation_space.shape))
model.add(Dense(16))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(nb_actions))
model.add(Activation('linear'))
print(model.summary())
```

Fitting that model to DQN model from keral-rl as follows:

```
policy = EpsGreedyQPolicy()
memory = SequentialMemory(limit=50000, window_length=1)
dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, nb_actions=nb_actions, memory=memory, nb_steps_warmup=10, target_model_update=0.001, policy=policy)
dqn.compile(Adam(lr=1e-3), metrics=['mse', 'mae'])
dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=5000, visualize=False, verbose=3)
```

The error is from this line:

```
dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, nb_actions=nb_actions, memory=memory, nb_steps_warmup=10, target_model_update=0.001, policy=policy)
```

I am using keras-rl==0.4.2 and tensorflow==2.1.0. Based on other answers, I also tried tensorflow==2.0.0-beta0 but it doesn't solve the error.

Can someone please explain to me why I am facing this error? and how to solve it?

Thank you.

Comment: What is `env`?  Where is the `len` taking place? Or is it part of the callbacks?

Comment: `env` is a gym game environment for training RL model. `len` is taking place somewhere in the TensorFlow library. I've updated the question for more details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason this breaks is because, `tf.Tensor` TF 2.0.0 (and TF 1.15) has the `__len__` overloaded and [raises an exception](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/590d6eef7e91a6a7392c8ffffb7b58f2e0c8bc6b/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L738). But TF 1.14 for example doesn't have the `__len__` attribute.

Therefore, anything TF 1.15+ (inclusive) breaks `keras-rl` (specifically [here](https://github.com/keras-rl/keras-rl/blob/216c3145f3dc4d17877be26ca2185ce7db462bad/rl/agents/dqn.py#L108)), which gives you the above error. So you got two options,

- Downgrade to TF 1.14 (recommended)
- Delete the [`__len__`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/590d6eef7e91a6a7392c8ffffb7b58f2e0c8bc6b/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L738) overloading in TensorFlow source (**not recommended** as this can break other things)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's working perfectly on TF 1.14.

Answer (score 2):

a temporal solution for me was to change this line

```
if hasattr(model.output, '__len__') and len(model.output) > 1:
```

in the agentfile, where the error come from, in my case dqn.py to :

```
if hasattr(model.output, '__len__') and len([model.output.shape.dims.__len__()]) > 1:
```